# c# TcpClient ожидание данных

Tags: c#, tcp-ip

Раз в n минут приходят данные на 4001 порт, можно ли ожидать(поймать) появление новых данных без использования цикла `while`?

Пример:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 4001))
{
    while(true)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вас заботит то, что вы блокируете поток, или сам цикл `while`?

Comment: @andreycha заботит ощущение что `while(true)` это не правильно.

Comment: Цикл ``while(true)`` можно вполне легально остановить с помощью ``break``

Answer (score -1):

Ну в целом можно. While всего лишь означает, что цикл должен идти с момента когда его запустили до момента пока либо не закроют программу, либо не вылезет неотловленный Exception. Если написать без цикла, то будет получен только 1 результат, то есть если что-то пришло в тот же момент, что и подключение.

Теоретически можно заменить его на кучу таймеров запускаемых один за другим через *n* минут или придумать еще какой-нибудь непотребный изврат.

В целом же конструкция `while(true)` тоже вариант плохой, т.к. не предусматривает закрытие соединения со стороны сервера. Хороший вариант это проверять количество полученных битов. Соответственно если сервер или клиент закроет соединение `socket.Receive()` вернет `-1`.

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 4001)) {
    int bytesRead;
    socket = client .Client;
    while((bytesRead = socket.Receive(buffer)) > 0) {
    }
}
```